# Removing Ghost possession without a Cleric or Paladin

Tags: dnd-5e, undead, possession

I have a small group of adventures. One of them is playing [Matt Mercer's "Blood Hunter" class](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/170777/Blood-Hunter-Class) also described [on Geek & Sundry](http://geekandsundry.com/matt-mercer-presents-the-blood-hunter-class-for-dd/). A large part of the story for him is hunting undead creatures. One of the undead I want to use is ghost, but the party has no cleric or paladin.

Is there a way to remove possession other than some of the ones here: [Are There Any Mechanics for Removing Possession?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78514/are-there-any-mechanics-for-removing-possession)

I thought about Turn Undead, but again, they have no cleric or paladin. Is there another way to remove it that I am missing?

Comment: This *seems* to just be checking if there's extra answer material for that other question not already mentioned; usually the approach there is to start a bounty on the existing question (e.g. "draw attention").

Comment: I looked for an existing question, can you point me to a better one than the one I found? The question they have is more about a story hook, IMO, but I could be wrong?

Comment: Why is the ghost a CR 4 (same as an elephant)?  An elephant doesn't make a party expend their abilities knocking each other out as it hops, immune to most damage, from possessing one party member to the next, possibly recharging during the possession.   Letting the victim save every round would make it a level 4 monster.  You could disarm them or run and wait for them to succeed on their saving throw.  CR 4 only with a cleric who has the appropriate spells ready (and doesn't get possessed).

Comment: There are a number of calculators and resources on calculating CR. The one in the book suggests calculating the Offensive and Defensive CRs and then doing an average of them. My guess is that a "possession" had to be estimated in the CR calculation. It would be difficult to calculate, plus a ghost might be able to be reasoned with... If this question remains for you, I'd suggest asking it so others could weigh in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The DMG lists the various ways to get a ghost out of a person. It's pretty much exhaustive. So, here we go. The possession lasts until:

**The body drops to zero hit points** Any party can handle beating someone up. Healing potion to bring the victim back is optional.

**The ghost ends it as a bonus action** This requires voluntary action on the part of the ghost. Options include negotiating with it to leave, or tricking it into leaving (possibly by offering a better host).

**The ghost is turned or forced out** Explicitly called out here are *Dispel Good And Evil* as well as *Turn Undead*. The best option is, of course, to have a character who can cast/use that in the party. One alternative to that is recruiting/renting such a person. The other seems to be finding a magic item that can cast the spell.

Comment: I knew option 1 and 3, I hadn't considered the ghost could try to find a better host. Great answer!

Comment: While I appreciate your enthusiasm, it's more traditional to only accept answers at least a day or two after the question is posted. I may well have missed some really cool options in the core books or one of the half dozen expansions, so you might get a better answer. You should be able to unaccept this if you like, and accept it later if you still think it's the best answer. Cheers!

Comment: Option 1 is the "Shoot the Hostage" plan

Comment: @JoelHarmon You may wish to add that a DM can (and should under the right circumstances, like this one) give a chance of a saving throw under his own judgment (DMG 238), even if the ability does not include the option. In this particular case, while the PC is conscious the DM can give every round the possessed PC a saving throw chance: CHA would be the one, since it represent the "force of personality".