# How does a fiend possess a creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, possession

Since [1974](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)) fiendish creatures have evolved, gaining and losing many powers and spells down through the ages. Through all of this, the mechanics of *possession* are ellusive.

Please note all editions of D&D have had careful descriptions on *possession* when needed - note the (in)famous [ghost](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Ghost#content). It explains how the living target-creature would lose control, which stats change (or not) and how the etherial form phases into a material body. The mechanics are exacting and have really effective game-play usage. It is great.

Contrast this with the 5e [Shadow demon](https://www.aidedd.org/dnd/monstres.php?vo=shadow-demon): in the writeup they lay claim to some ability to possess targets - yet mechanics for this ability seem to be missing. Most other fiends seem to be devoid of all mind control powers all together. Even the almighty [Pit Fiend](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Pit%20Fiend#content)'s only mind alteration does not extend beyond causing enemies to be a bit scared... for a possible six seconds. On a failed save. Once a day. Provided one is not otherwise immune.

It would add a lot to a campaign to have anyone, characters, player characters or even the players themselves (open for anything here), possessed by a demon. Note that StackExchange even features a brilliant write-up on how to be rid of a demon once one has been taken over - this is a [Step-By-Step / 'How-To'](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78514/are-there-any-mechanics-for-removing-possession). It is very good.

**Long story short:** how do demons possess (player or non-) characters? Where are the mechanics listed?

Comment: Are you asking for someone to review each official monster, list the ones that can possess, and then write out the mechanics for them?

Comment: There were mechanics for demonic possession in D&D 3rd edition, but I don't know the mechanics for 5th.

Comment: Or are you asking if there are general always-on rules for all fiends to possess?

Comment: I am asking if there is a specific rule-mechanic for fiends to possess one or more creature types. The example of 'ghost possession' is only listed because it is so specific-exacting - and so useful! For example, a ghost cannot possess an ogre ('giant') nor a mind flayer ('aberration') - despite how 'humanoid' they appear. Clear guidelines for *fiend-possession* would be valuable / handy!

Comment: To confirm, you're asking the question in my 2nd comment: if there are always-on general possession mechanics available to all fiends?

Answer (score 2):

### They get bound in an object, then escape the object to enter a mortal soul

It says on p. 51 of the *Monster Manual* in the section on ***Bound Demons***:

> ...ancient tomes describe techniques that can trap the essence of a demon... within a weapon, idol, or piece of jewelery...

and further on the same page under ***Demonic Possession***:

> No matter how secure its bindings, a powerful demon often finds a way to escape an object that holds it. When a demonic essence emerges from its container, it can possess a mortal host.

So, this is an exception to the usual tendency of demons to have their essence return immediately to the Abyss when they are without a vivified body (i.e, when they are killed), as is explained on pp. 50,51 of the *Monster Manual* in the section, "Eternal Evil."

What is not specified, is *how* a "powerful demon... finds a way to escape" its container.  But this gives you an overall framework or "backstory" for your demon possession: some spellcaster must have summoned and bound your demon inside an object, and then the demon must have found a way to escape that object, thereby giving the demon the chance to possess a mortal soul instead of going to the Abyss.

Answer (score 0):

### They don't

[WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) - if it doesn't say it, it doesn't do it.

Comment: On the contrary. It says they do, but doesn't say anything about the mechanics of how.